# Floating Items in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am looking for a way to have objects float on a web bowser.
I would like items like pictures and Tables of data to be displayed on the screen and the user can move it around like how you would move windows and icons on a desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery UI draggable and droppable demos at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

---

Added Link to jQuery Portlets

[Portlets](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets)

Comment: Is it possible to make it work like a window? what i mean is if you wish to move a window you would click on the top part and drag it but with this (the demo), you could click on anything and drag it

Comment: That's a little out of my experience at the moment but hopefully this answer on SO will be some help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225226/asp-net-web-parts-drag-and-drop-support-in-non-ie-browsers/2271892#2271892.  Also take a look at this http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets